# What were Cicero's original contributions to philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, cicero

While reading history of philosophy books, [Cicero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero)'s name often comes up. However I remain unclear of what if any are his original contributions to the philosophy of that period.

I know that he was an important transmitter of philosophical though from the Greek to the Roman world and so onto the modern period. However [Sextus Empiricus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextus_Empiricus) and [Diogenes Laertius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_La%C3%ABrtius) were also important transmitters of philosophical knowledge but they get much more of a passing reference in the history books.

I know that Cicero was an important political figure, an adherent of the [skeptic school](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism) (to a greater or lesser extent) and I believe that his prose is meant to be magnificent (though I'm no classicist). But what did he add to philosophy itself?

Many thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Cicero's main contribution to philosophy was in political philosophy. The extensive account of his idea was only found in the nineteenth century.

> **His big idea**, which he tirelessly publicized, was that of a mixed or balanced constitution. He favored not monarchy nor oligarchy nor democracy, but a combination of all three. His model was Rome itself, but improved. Its executive had quasi-royal powers. It was restrained partly by the widespread use of vetoes and partly by a Senate, dominated by great political families. Politicians were elected to office by the People. [My emphasis.]

<sup>From [Anthony Everitt's *Cicero*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/84593.Cicero).</sup>

However, looking at [Wikipedia's 'Mixed government' entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_government), this doesn't appear to be much of a novel idea at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Cicero Latinised philosophy

Cicero pioneered the writing of philosophy in Latin rather than Greek:

> **In the Tusculans, the Academica, De Officiis,
>    De Divinatione, and De Finibus Cicero promoted Latin, in terms very like those of
>    modern linguistic nationalism, as a medium for intellectual discourse at the expense
>    of Greek, and exhorted his readers to follow him in transferring philosophy from
>    Greece to Rome.** To choose to write philosophy at this time in Latin instead of Greek
>    was, as Cicero put it, a practical means of increasing Rome's intellectual prestige, a
>    campaign in which he invited his readers to enlist. But to whom was this appeal
>    directed? Who, to Cicero's mind at least, would have been useful in achieving this
>    political goal? From evidence in Cicero's letters to Atticus, we can largely retrace how
>    he disseminated these philosophical books, reconstruct to some degree their original
>    readers, and, most importantly, deduce the grounds on which Cicero selected them.
>    Cicero's choice of audience, and the manner in which he assembled it, throws an
>    interesting light both on his agenda in promoting Latin as a philosophical language
>    as well as on the Roman culture of publication.
>
> Before we look at the means by which Cicero's books were disseminated, we must
>    look first, very briefly, at the linguistic politics of the Roman intellectual world in the
>    first century B.C., and review what Cicero thought he was achieving by writing philo-
>    sophy in Latin. **Cicero pioneered the use of Latin prose as a vehicle for philosophy,
>    permanently expanding its supply of abstract vocabulary in the process. His own
>    linguistic facility permanently extended the expressive capacities of Latin, leaving it a
>    more supple, and more prestigious, medium of thought.** Such is the point of an
>    elegantly turned compliment, preserved for us by Pliny the Elder, to Cicero from
>    Caesar himself: 'You have earned a laurel greater than that of any triumph, insofar as
>    it is greater to have extended the boundaries of the Roman mind than those of Roman power.'

(T. Murphy, 'Cicero's First Readers: Epistolary Evidence for the Dissemination of His Works', The Classical Quarterly, Vol. 48, No. 2 (1998), pp. 492-505: 492-3.)

The whole credit for Latin's subsequent status as the main means of philosophical exposition, discussion, and debate can hardly be awarded to Cicero but he played a major role in Latin's later status as the *lingua franca* of philosophy in Western Europe.